# Separate a five digit integer such as 12345 into 1 2 3 4 5, separating each digit with a tab

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;

    cout << "Please enter a 5 digit integer.";
    cin >> x;

    a= x%10 ;
    b= x%100 %10;
    c= x%1000 %10;
    d= x%10000 %10;
    e= x%100000 %10;

    cout << a
         << b
         << c
         << d
         << e;


    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have so far but I can't seem to cout<< each digit all at once with a tab.I need to add a tab in between each one of the digits.

Comment: I wonder why you don't just read a `string` from `cin` and write that split by tabs to `cout` instead.

Comment: if you want to read it as an integer, then you can use a simple loop to make the process much more simple

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a problem. If you want a tab between each digit, just put it there:

```
cout << a << '\t'
     << b << '\t'
     << c << '\t'
     << d << '\t'
     << e << '\n';
```

However, this cries out for a loop-based solution, something like:

```
for (int div = 10000; div > 0; div /= 10)
    cout << (x / div) % 10 << '\t';
```

Or, if you want the last one to be a newline rather than a tab:

```
for (int div = 10000; div > 1; div /= 10)
    cout << (x / div) % 10 << '\t';
cout << x % 10 << '\n';
```

---

Your expressions calculating `a/b/c/d/e` are wrong by the way, they will all give you the last digit. If you still don't want to use the loop method, at least fix that:

```
a= x / 10000;
b= x /  1000 % 10;
c= x /   100 % 10;
d= x /    10 % 10;
e= x         % 10;
```

Comment: Professor hasn't taught loops yet and discouraged it even though it would be easier... Now I am just getting the last digit of the integer repeated 5 times with a tab like so 5    5    5    5    5

Answer (score 0):

use

```
cout<<a<<'\t'<<b<<'\t'<<c<<'\t'<<d'\t'<<e;
```

EDIT

For your problem, change the formula to:

```
a= x/10000   %10;
b= x/1000    %10;
c= x/100     %10;
d= x/10      %10;
e= x         %10;
```

Comment: Okay that worked to add a tab however it now will cout<< 5   5   5   5   5    5